# How can I create a pause button for a tag like <audio> or <video>

Tags: html

As the title suggests, I have audio playing automatically in my site, and some visitors have recommended that I create a pause button for it. After trying numerous online javascript based solutions, I have come out with no success. I use the following code for the audio to play:

```html
<audio id= "song" autoplay loop onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `controls` to tag `<audio>`

example:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: A little documentation to support your answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<!-- add a button to control the audio -->
<button id="btn">Pause</button>
```

**Js**

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
    songAudio = document.querySelector('#song');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (songAudio.paused) { // toggle the audio and button
        songAudio.play();
        btn.textContent = 'Pause';
    } else {
        songAudio.pause();
        btn.textContent = 'Play';
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you probably got it because code only answers are discouraged. You are basically correct, but you should flesh out your answer more. I'd suggest add some mark up for the pause button and show creating the event handler for the button. If you can add a resource like : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio, even better

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Source:/

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

**Jquery;**

```
$(function(){
 $('audio').click(function() {
   if (this.paused !== false) {
       this.play();
   } else {
       this.pause();
   }
 });
});
```